# View SOAP XML from WCF Creating Client

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap

I have created a WCF Client with the SVCUTIL.exe following these instructions : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133.aspx

It creates a app.config and a soapproxy.cs file to use.

I can not figure out any way of getting the raw XML for debugging purposes.

Google has lots of examples with adding a traceextension to the web.config file, however I do not have a web.config file... And the examples I found are for web.service not System.ServiceModel;

I need to access the XML soap calls so I can debug it?

UPDATE:
I am trying to edit the config trace to view the SOAP XML.

I have added this to the app.config file

```
<configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
                    switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                    propagateActivity="true">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="xml" />
                </listeners>
            </source>
            <source name="CardSpace">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="xml" />
                </listeners>
            </source>
            <source name="System.IO.Log">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="xml" />
                </listeners>
            </source>
            <source name="System.Runtime.Serialization">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="xml" />
                </listeners>
            </source>
            <source name="System.IdentityModel">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="xml" />
                </listeners>
            </source>
     </sources>

        <sharedListeners>
            <add name="xml"
                 type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                 initializeData="c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
       </sharedListeners>
    </system.diagnostics>
    </configuration>
```

However the trace log that comes up does not seem to include the raw XML

Comment: See [Configuring Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx).

Comment: have you tried using a proxy, such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)?

Comment: Fiddler doesnt seem to give me waht i need to see, perhapes because it is encoding it?

Comment: Ensure permissions from the IIS user on that directory. Could be the IIS user cannot write to that file/directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For quick debugging I use the WCF Test Client. Its quite simple and works with WCF and ASMX services. I also use it to consume services from third party applications written in Java (with wsdl definitions).

`Start -> Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt -> wcftestclient.exe`

or

`Start -> Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt -> wcftestclient.exe`

Information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx

This has the ability to view the XML/SOAP request and response.

Also I use the XMLTraceListener. This generates the trace for me inside my application path and I am able to view the entire request/response body.

Here is my web.Config section

```xml
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="All">
            <listeners>
                <add name="xmlTraceListener" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="All">
            <listeners>
                <add name="xmlTraceListener" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add name="xmlTraceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="ApplicationTrace.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
</system.diagnostics>
```