# Viewing the HTTP Headers from a WCF service

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap, http-headers

I am following the following example for my first experience with WCF.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx

I follow the routine and these are the XML codes that I can find with the inbuilt WCF Test Client that comes with Visual Studio 2010.

`Request` :-

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <GetData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <value>re</value>
    </GetData>
  </s:Body>
```

`Response` :-

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <GetDataResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetDataResult>You entered: re</GetDataResult>
    </GetDataResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I m trying to figure out where and how I can view the 200 OK http response message. It is probably happening somewhere in the background and I would like some help to figure out where to find it.

I have looked online and searched on google, still cant find it.

Comment: You would need to use something like Fiddler to see the HTTP headers. That's a different level of protocol. You might be able to sort of see them using WCF [Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730342.aspx)

Comment: Does WCF use HTTP by default when it is added as a service reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something similar answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8318472/1384237

I prefer to use [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/), you can quickly view the raw content of the request and response, and achieve what you want.

Comment: This might seem silly, but where does the SoapUI utility tool fit into this? I downloaded it, but I am not sure how to integrate that with visual studios wcf test client. I add the wsdl file from my project to the SoapUI interface, and send a request, `<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> <s:Body> <GetDataResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> <GetDataResult>You entered: ?dfsfdsfdsfds</GetDataResult> </GetDataResponse> </s:Body> </s:Envelope>` This is the response XML I get.. but where is the http 200 OK response? I must be misunderstanding something.

Comment: Also, a new thing I noticed with soapui.... I create a web service using c# and publish it on the test server. Run the soapui, point to the server wsdl address and run the compliance tool... I get wsdl reference set to local desktop... I log into a new local client and do the same process and the reference within the compliance tool is now set to the new local desktop...why?

Comment: finally got soapUI to show the 200 OK http message. It was under the "raw" - tab of the response message.

Comment: sory was a bit offline this last days, glad you found you're way :D

Answer (score 1):

I often use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) in conjunction with the aforementioned WCF Test Client to inspect HTTP traffic using the BasicHttpBinding with WCF.

Comment: I tried using Fiddler, and it works great when I start it up to inspect all internet traffic http headers. However it doesn't pick up the Microsoft Visual Studio Service.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the Visual Studio Service - do you mean when you're debugging locally? If so, this is a known limitation of Fiddler due to the Windows TCP/IP stack - essentially you can get around the limitation by accessing the service via machine name instead of localhost or a loopback IP, see http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-LocalTraffic

Comment: As an addendum, you probably will want to use the process filter in Fiddler to only display traffic to/from the WCF test client so you aren't innudated with noise while debugging your services.

Comment: I tried adding the `static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession:Fiddler.Session){ if (oSession.HostnameIs("MYAPP")) { oSession.host = "127.0.0.1:8081"; } }` rule to Fiddler. however still no result. "MYApp" = 'wcftestclient'. and loopback address is '127.0.0.1:49236'. I also tried using the Microsoft Service Trace Viewer, which does show me the loopback xml traffic, however I m still failing to see the actual 'http 200 OK' part of the xml traffic.

Comment: And you're using `http://wcftestclient` from WCF test client to access your service running loclaly on port 49236?

Comment: It seems to be that way for me.